# how can i convert list of sentences to IOB format, saving the sentences separation in the output

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger, crf

i have some txt file which i need to convert to IOB format for CRF model.

Using nltk tree2conlltags i can convert tokenized, postagged text into IOB format that i need.

Like this

```
("u'Is", 'JJ', u'O')
('Miami', 'NNP', u'B-PERSON')
('playing', 'NN', u'O')
('in', 'IN', u'O')
('Washigthon', 'NNP', u'B-GPE')
('this', 'DT', u'O')
('month', 'NN', u'O')
('?', '.', u'O')
```

But the problem is that as output i get one word as one element, but i need one sentence as element.

Also i tried firstly separate text into sentences and then tokenize them, so i'll save sentences boundAries, but nltk pos tagger doesn't accept list type data.

Maybe there is the whole new approach to get the format i need or

Comment: If you want to have one element per sentence, then what are your labels? Obviously, you don't want PoS tags and named entities, since they don't make much sense at the sentence level. Please show us an example how the output should look like.

Comment: Also, why is your first token `"u'Is"`? It looks like somewhere `repr()` was called on the input string.

Comment: i want to have one sentence as element but i still need all postagging and ner labels, cause i need them for conditional random fields, i dont quite understand why the first token "Is" is a problem, its just beginning of a sentence

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of how the data should look like. And for the first token: If you can't see that it isn't `"Is"`, but actually `"u'Is"` (with a "u" inside the quotes), then never mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to concatenate the tokens, PoS tags and the NER labels into one string each for every sentence, eg. like this (`token_wise` is the data from your example):

```
>>> tuple(' '.join(layer) for layer in zip(*token_wise))
("u'Is Miami playing in Washigthon this month ?",
 'JJ NNP NN IN NNP DT NN .',
 'O B-PERSON O O B-GPE O O O')
```

You'd have to repeat that for each sentence.
But it doesn't make any sense. Your CRF tagger will have no chance to predict a complex label like `'O B-PERSON O O B-GPE O O O'`, because you'll have a huge sparse-data problem.
Most labels will only be seen once, and even more so the input sentences.

Also, this is not IOB format. In IOB, you have either I, O, or B per element, but not a combination of them.

Comment: but this is what i have I, O, or B per element, but i already solved the problem, thanks for your help